# Fail while installing dynamic web module2.5

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jakarta-ee

I Just import a Java based, maven web project but when i am trying to change Project facet in eclipse by rightclick on Project->Properties->Project facet i am getting

> Fail while installing dynamic web module2.5

Answer (score 0):

From command prompt go to  **workspace/myproject**
and run the following command

```
 mvn eclipse:eclipse -Dwtpversion=2.0
```